# R - extracing data from a mhtml file into excel

Tags: html, r, html-table

I have the following data set (from a meassuring device) in a mhtml file. The structure of this file is always the same (as in, the way it is formatted is always the same from the Data). The desired goal now are the following things

- Extract the data from the tables and save them in a tabular form, so that I can access it via Excel (can be done using ´rvest´ and then using the ´html_table´ function and than save the desired tables in a csv/xls file)
- Extract the data from the blob in the end and save them in a tabular form, so that I can access it via Excel

Basically, I need to analyse the data, hence I need them in a excel sheet.

Thing is, the "blob" of data is not in a tabluar form, so 'html_table´ doesn't work (it is basically in the last table cell). The following solution sadly doesn't work either, since the table function screws it up (it works perfectly fine without the table):

```
library(magrittr)
makeHTML2Table <- function(text) 
{
  text %>% gsub("\\s|=|#","",.) %>% str_split(.,"<br>") %>% unlist %>% gsub("&nbsp","",.) %>% gsub("^;+|;+$","",.) %>%
    str_split(.,pattern = ";+") %>% data.table::transpose(.) %>% data.table::transpose(.) %>% do.call(rbind,.)
}

makeHTML2Table(bigString)
```

(thanks to Andre Elrico for your help here)

Has anybody an idea on how to solve this issue?

Data:

```
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/related;
        boundary="=_nextpart_of_BAUR_MHTML";
        type="text/html"
    X-MimeOLE: Producted by BAUR.

    This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

    --=_nextpart_of_BAUR_MHTML
    Content-Type: text/html;
        charset="Windows-1252"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
    Content-Location: file://C:\BaurMeasure\Ax00E4nde_21152 VB_20180124120429\A=e4nde | 2/7 A=e4nde | 2/1152 B=
    s.htm


    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

    <html>

    <head>

    <title>A=e4nde | 2/7 Al=e4nde | 2/1152 B=
    s</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <p style=3d" text-align:right"> 
    <img src=3d"file:///=
    C:/BaurSoftware/daten/Kaernten-Netz-Logo+Endorsement-4C.png =
    " width=3d20% alt=3d""> </p>

    <p style=3d"margin-left:70%;text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal; text-decoration:none"><br></p><hr noshade>

    <p style=3d"text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial; font-size:24pt; font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;
     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">td</p><p>&nbsp;</p>

    <table align=3dcenter>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:16pt; font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Projekt
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal; text-decoration:none">

    &nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    <table align=3dcenter>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Name des Projektes:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Al=e4nde
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Zusatzinformation:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">


    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Von S:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    2/7 Al=e4nde
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Nach S:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    2/1152 B
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">


    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Zeit:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    12:58
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Datum:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    XXXXX
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">


    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Name des Pr=fcfers:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    abc
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Kommentar:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Mantelpr=fcfung durchgef=fchrt:<br><br>L1: 20=b5A<br>L2: 12=b5A<br>L3:&#x20;=
    4=b5A
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <table align=3dcenter>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:16pt; font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Kabeldaten
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal; text-decoration:none">

    &nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    <table align=3dcenter>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">


    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Typ:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    dta
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Hersteller:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">


    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Nennspannung:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    20
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Anzahl der Phasen:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    3
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Phasenbezeichnung:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    L1
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    L2
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    L3
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Verlegejahr:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    1981
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>L=e4nge:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    154.0 m
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i><b>Ausbreitungsgeschwind.:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i>
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    80.1 m/us
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    <p style=3d"page-break-after:always">&nbsp;</p>

    <hr noshade>

    <p style=3d"text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial; font-size:16pt; font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;
     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">Messung</p><p style=3d" text-align:center"> 
    <img src=3d"file:///c:/BaurSoftware/daten/TDBitmap0.png =
    " width=3d100% alt=3d"TD Measure"> </p>

    <p style="border-width:3px;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFF00;padding:10;text-align:center;font-family:Arial;font-size:16pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;text-decoration:none;color:#000000">Cable with operating risk!</p><p style=3d"text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt; font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;
     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">Auswertung</p><table align=3dcenter>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <b>Name der Auswertung</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    XLPE
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i>Kriterium</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    <i>Kommentar</i>
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    TD(n+1)-TD(n) > 0.0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Cable with very high operating risk. Measurement cancelled!
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    TD(n) > 0.0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Cable with very high operating risk. Measurement cancelled!
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    TD(n+1)-TD(n) > 1.0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Cable with high operating risk!
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    TD(n) > 2.2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Cable with high operating risk!
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    TD(n+1)-TD(n) > 0.6&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Cable with operating risk!
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    TD(n) > 1.2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Cable with operating risk!
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    No criterion matches&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>

    </td>

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    Cable can be returned to service
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    <p style=3d"text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial; font-size:16pt; font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;
     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">Protocol of actual Measurement</p><p style=3d"text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial; font-size:16pt; font-style:normal;font-weight:bolder;
     text-decoration:none; color:#000000">Details</p><table align=3dcenter>

    <tr >

    <td style=3d"text-align:left; vertical-align:top">

    <p style=3d"text-align:left;font-family:Courier New; font-size:10pt; font-style:normal;=

    font-weight:bolder; text-decoration:none; color:#000000">

    #&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;t&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;U&nbs=
    p;&nbsp;I&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;we&nbsp;ta&nbsp;<br>&nb=
    sp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&=
    nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;kV&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;mA&=
    nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;E-3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&n=
    bsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>--------------------------------------------=
    -----------<br>1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13:02:57&nbsp;&nbsp;5.8&nbsp;&nbsp;&=
    nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.14&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0=
    .39&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13:03:07=
    &nbsp;&nbsp;5.8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.14&nbsp;&nb=
    sp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.39&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br=
    >3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13:03:17&nbsp;&nbsp;5.8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nb=
    sp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.14&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.39&nbsp;&nbsp=
    ;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13:03:27&nbsp;&nbsp;5.=
    8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.14&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp=
    ;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.39&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>5&nbsp;&nbsp;=
    &nbsp;13:03:37&nbsp;&nbsp;5.8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp=
    ;0.14&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.39&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&=
    nbsp;&nbsp;<br>6&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13:03:47&nbsp;&nbsp;5.8&nbsp;&nbsp;&=
    nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.14&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0=
    .39&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>7&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13:03:57=
    &nbsp;&nbsp;5.8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.14&nbsp;&nb=
    sp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.39&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br=
    >8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;13:04:08&nbsp;&nbsp;5.8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nb=
    sp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.14&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.39&nbsp;&nbsp=
    ;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>Phase&nbsp;.......................&nb=
sp;:&nbsp;L1<br>Datum/Zeit&nbsp;..................&nbsp;:&nbsp;24-01-2=
018&nbsp;13:04:08<br>Stufe&nbsp;.......................&nbsp;:&nbsp;1<=
br>tan-delta-Mittelwert&nbsp;........&nbsp;:&nbsp;0.390&nbsp;E-3<br>St=
andardabweichung&nbsp;..........&nbsp;:&nbsp;0.002&nbsp;E-3<br>Anzahl&=
nbsp;der&nbsp;Messungen&nbsp;........&nbsp;:&nbsp;8<br>Last&nbsp;.....=
...................&nbsp;:&nbsp;38.5&nbsp;nF<br>Pr=fcfobjekt&nbsp;VSE-=
Strom&nbsp;........&nbsp;:&nbsp;32&nbsp;=b5A<br>Generator&nbsp;VSE-Str=
om&nbsp;.........&nbsp;:&nbsp;2&nbsp;=b5A<br>
    </p>

    </td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    <p style=3d"page-break-after:always">&nbsp;</p>

    <hr noshade>

    <!-- Start Inhalt -->

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, I was able to extraction the text of an mht file with R :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate2("C:\\Users\\...\\file.mht")
text <- IEApp$Document()$documentElement()$innerText()
```